# How do align two elements in a div (excluding the heading) in a same line with gap?

Tags: html, css

I have a `html` code:

```
<div class="bg-text">
    <h4><u>Newspaper particulars</u></h4><br>
    <label for="date">Select date :</label><br>
    <input type="date" id="date" name="date" style="text-align: center;"><br><br>
    <label for="news">Select newspaper :</label><br>
    <select name="news" id="news" style="text-align: center;">
        <option value="default">Click to select</option>
        <option value="The Assam Tribune">The Assam Tribune</option>
        <option value="The Times of India">The Times of India</option>
        <option value="The Hindu">The Hindu</option>
        <option value="Hindustan Times">Hindustan Times</option>
        <option value="The Telegraph">The Telegraph</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And my `css`:

```
.bg-text {
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 2;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I want to have the two input tags (`date` and `select`) on the same line, along with their labels (which will be on the left side of their respective input tags). How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added some in line css and class with `display:flex;` and margins

```css
.bg-text {
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 2;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.center-y{
  margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto; 
}

label{
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.center-x{
  margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; 
}

.margins{
  margin-right: 5px; margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-text" style="display:flex; flex-direction: column;">
    <h4><u>Newspaper particulars</u></h4><br>
  <div style="display: flex;" class="center-x">
    <label class="center-y margins" for="date">Select date :</label><br>
    <input type="date" id="date" name="date" style="text-align: center;"><br><br>
    <label class="center-y margins" for="news">Select newspaper :</label><br>
    <select name="news" id="news" style="text-align: center;">
        <option value="default">Click to select</option>
        <option value="The Assam Tribune">The Assam Tribune</option>
        <option value="The Times of India">The Times of India</option>
        <option value="The Hindu">The Hindu</option>
        <option value="Hindustan Times">Hindustan Times</option>
        <option value="The Telegraph">The Telegraph</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I increase the gap between the two inputs?

Comment: On the second label you can add ```margin-left``` or you can modify the ```.margins``` class @Abhishek

Comment: No, I mean the gap between `Select date: dd/mm/yyyy` and `Select newspaper: Click to select`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="bg-text">
    <h4><u>Newspaper particulars</u></h4><br>
    <div>
        <label for="date">Select date :</label><br>
        <input type="date" id="date" name="date" style="text-align: center;"><br><br>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="news">Select newspaper :</label><br>
        <select name="news" id="news" style="text-align: center;">
            <option value="default">Click to select</option>
            <option value="The Assam Tribune">The Assam Tribune</option>
            <option value="The Times of India">The Times of India</option>
            <option value="The Hindu">The Hindu</option>
            <option value="Hindustan Times">Hindustan Times</option>
            <option value="The Telegraph">The Telegraph</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

    .bg-text {
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
        justify-content:space-around;
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
        position: absolute;
        top: 20%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        z-index: 2;
        width: 80%;
        padding: 20px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .bg-text>div{display:flex;align-items:center;}
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: Question says "Except the header"